# Appending Text to mathematical operation result in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, append

I'm converting bytes to human readable format. At the end of the result, it should be appending if it is MB or KB or just bytes. I'm unable to find right way to do it.

Sqlite table content.

```
+-----------+
| Data Sent |
+-----------+
| 17210032  |
+-----------+
| 60080929  |
+-----------+
| 64061961  |
+-----------+
| 29894     |
+-----------+
| 862       |
+-----------+
```

Sqlite Code for conversion from bytes to human readable

```
select "Data Sent",
CASE 
    WHEN "Data Sent" > 1024*1024 then round("Data Sent"*1.0/(1024*1024), 2)
    WHEN "Data Sent" > 1024 then round("Data Sent"*1.0/(1024), 2)
    WHEN "Data Sent" < 1024 then "Data Sent"
ELSE NULL
end as conv_data
from testdb
```

The first condition is to convert from bytes to Mega Bytes. Second one is for KB and last one is bytes.

Expected Result:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Data Sent | conv_data |
+-----------+-----------+
| 17210032  | 16.41 MB  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 60080929  | 57.3 MB   |
+-----------+-----------+
| 64061961  | 61.09 MB  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 29894     | 29.19 KB  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 862       | 862 bytes |
+-----------+-----------+
```

but current code just shows converted numbers. How can we append MB, KB, bytes to the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQLite Concatenation **`||`** e.g. :-

```
SELECT "Data Sent",
CASE 
        WHEN "Data Sent" < 1024 THEN "Data Sent" || " Bytes."
        WHEN "Data Sent" > 1024  AND "Data Sent" < 1048576 THEN round("Data Sent" * 1.0 / 1024,2) || " KB."
        WHEN "Data Sent" > (1024 * 1024) THEN round("Data Sent" * 1.0/ (1024 * 1024),2) || " MB."
END AS conv_data
from testdb;
```

Note! No need for ELSE clause for NULL check, as results will be NULL.

Results in :-

[image]